# How to render the formated text in the report.rdlc (with its format)

Tags: html, asp.net, css, reporting-services, rdlc

I store my data in formatted way in my db ,
I want some way to render the text with its format in my `report.rdlc` i use visual studio 2008 How to do this :

---

For example :

if my text like this :

```
<p>text</p>
```

It appears the same with tags in my report text box !!. instead of rendering as a paragraph.

---

when i bind like this :

```
= Fields.subject
```

How to fix this problem ?

---

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Edit**

After researching this problem a bit more it appears Visual Studio doesn't support Markup as HTML for `rdlc` reports until Visual Studio 2010. So if upgrading is an option, then you can do what you want.

Otherwise you could always just strip out the HTML tags like so:

On the `Report` menu, click `Report Properties...` and select the `Code` tab. Enter the following code:

```
Function StripHTMLTags(ByVal text as String) AS String
  Return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(text, "<(.|\n)*?>", "")
End Function
```

Now in your cell use the following expression:

```
=Code.StripHTMLTags(Fields!MyField.Value)
```

*Original answer follows:*

Leaving aside that you should separate data from presentation, you can render using HTML tags in Reporting Services, its just not very intuitive to find:

1. Left click the field you want to display so that the `<Expr>` tag is highlighted
2. Right click the highlighted `<Expr>` tag and choose `Placeholder Properties...`
3. On the `General` tab, select the `HTML- Interpret HTML tags as style` radio button

Only a limited number of tags are supported however. [This article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645967%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) tells your more.

**Screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: i use `visual studio 2008` and i can't find those steps :(

Comment: I use VS2008 as well. Click the field so that `<Expr>` is highlighted, then right-click it and choose `Placeholder Properties...` from the pop-up menu

Comment: Could u provide some screen shots cuz i didn't find any of these steps !! i have update my question with a screen shot of my `Right click Menu`

Comment: You don't have the field highlighted so you won't get that option. Left click the cell <I>first</I> so that the contents of the cell are highlighted. Then right-click the highlighted text.

Comment: @just_name check the updated answer, I added some ScreenShots.

Comment: @g.Raam :
I don't have this screen !! i do the steps but in vain .I update my question with a new screen shots .

Comment: If you delete what's in the field and then right-click, do you get a menu option "Create Placeholder"? If so, do that and set your expression from the popup menu and switch the markup type to HTML.

Comment: @just_name it seems to me you are having a different problem. What is the type of that row? If you just add the field like this: `[YourDatasetFieldName]` does it work?

Comment: @g.Raam Thanks for adding the screenshots

Comment: @g.Raam :it's an rdlc report , and i use table then in a specific cell i use right click ,then select expression and after that i select field from my dataset like `=Field.!other_desc.Value`

Comment: @just_name Did you try using `[other_desc]`? If you are using SSRS 2008, a tablix with a dataset correctly defined, using `[other_desc]` instead of `=Fields!other_desc.Value` should work. I would start there. With the expression selected, what box shows up when you select `Properties` in your screen shot?

Comment: @g.Raam : I don't use `SSRS` ,i use report viewer ,.rdlc report in viual studio 2008

Comment: @just_name Ok, I should've started with that then. What you must do is create a `Text Box` (Insert -> Text box), then insert your field there and you'll be able to see `Placeholder Properties` when you right-click the selected content. Hope it works

Comment: @g.Raam: should i insert the textbox in the table cell ?

Comment: @g.Raam: I try to that but the same problem no `Placeholder Properties` at all.Could u add a report item to a project in visual studio 2008 and try it please ..

Comment: @just_name Ok, I will. In 6h I will be able to do so and will get back to you with the results.

Comment: @just_name do you see Text Properties? Anything like this?

Comment: I'm sorry the delay, I was out this weekend. Just help me out here, do you know how to create a placeholder? When you click textbox properties, what box shows up?

Comment: It appears Visual Studio doesn't support HTML markup for RDLC reports until VS2010. Answer updated.

Comment: To see it easily, delete the content of the textbox.  Then when the text cursor is in the textbox, right click and you'll see "Create Placeholder".

You need to have the actual element in the textbox highlighted to see it - not the textbox.

Comment: @Adam thank you, that was the info I needed.  I think that info is probably worth adding as a supplementary answer considering the potential for comments to be deleted?

Answer (score 4):

1. Double click at field area
2. At Placeholder properties choose General > HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles

[image: field area]